# How to use a for loop to make a Stack of 10 Buckwheat waffles?

Tags: java, stack

How do I Complete my for loop and add the missing statement so the ten waffles are placed on the stack? And is my for loop correct? for(int k = 1; k<=10; k++)?

```
package waffles; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Stack; 

public class Waffles 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Stack<String> waffleStack= new Stack<String>(); 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

        String buckwheat = "Buckwheat waffle";  
        String blueberry = "milk waffle"; 
        String strawberry = "berry waffle";

        for(int k = 1; k<=10; k++)
        {
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation of the [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class?

Comment: Where is 10 waffles  in the code ?? shwetha

Comment: @Youngistan isn't it this ->  for(int k = 1; k<=10; k++)?

Comment: This is loop which will iterate 10 times from 1 to 10 .So you want to add this int in the stack ??

Comment: @Youngistan and how should I do that?

Comment: Shwetha added answer.Look it

Answer (score 1):

Just use `push` method of the Stack

You can do it like that:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    waffleStack.push(buckwheat);
}
```

Comment: The question is _"How do I Complete my for loop.."_

Comment: @Jakub Hr, but how can i assemble a stack of 10 buckwheat waffles using the for loop?! I know that i can add waffles by using waffleStack.push(buckwheat)

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can add 10 buckwheat waffles to your stack like that. It's not really hard to find how for loop works in Java btw.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop will iterate 10 times and if you want to add the integer number in the stack then use below code ::

```
     for(int k = 1; k<=10; k++)
        { 
         waffleStack.push(String.valueOf(k));  // Cast int to String
                         or
         waffleStack.push(buckwheat);  // Want to add buckwheat
        }
```

Comment: Hi thanks! But how can i specifically add buckwheat waffles this way?

Comment: If you talking about variable String buckwheat = "Buckwheat waffle";  then you only need to write  waffleStack.push(buckwheat);